# How to replace huge array with PHP generators

Tags: php, php-generators

Seeking your help to convert one big array with PHP generators.
Below is my code for which I need rework:
I am getting a result set from a service call and assigning all to an array:

```
foreach ($objects->result as $pointStdObject) {
  $pointStdObjects[] = $pointStdObject;
}
```

This piece of code is inside a while loop which queries for records with an offset of 1000.
Issue is $pointStdObjects[] tends to get very huge and I get PHP out of memory exception.

Later I again need to use this same array as:

```
foreach ($pointStdObjects as $pointStdObject) {
  $point = $this->pointFactory->createPointFromStdObject($pointStdObject);
  if (!$point) {
    continue;
  }
  $points[] = $point;
}
return $points;
```

Please suggest if we can leverage PHP generators or yield here

Comment: Why do you make copy of $objects->result? You could probably just return that and not make second array.

Answer (score 2):

```
function getStd()
{
   ///your code before that
    foreach ($objects->result as $pointStdObject) {
        yield $pointStdObject;
    }
}

function useStd()
{
    foreach (getStd() as $pointStdObject) {
        $point = $this->pointFactory->createPointFromStdObject($pointStdObject);
        if (!$point) {
            continue;
        }
        $points[] = $point;
    }
    return $points;
}
```